# Arabic Characters in URL

Tags: asp.net, url, arabic, dotnetnuke

I have created a website using DNN. The site has arabic characters in URL after the domain name. For example: `http://www.example.com/اسعارالعملات.aspx`.

My questions are:

1. Is this URL read by non Arabic supportive operating systems or browsers or will it give the user an error?
2. Is it good for SEO to have Arabic in URL or not?
3. Are there any other problems due to the use of Arabic characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit : To answer your question points directly.*

**[1]** Yes they will work fine due to Internationalized Resource Identifiers.

**[2]** If you are targeting Arabic search results then yes having arabic in the url bar is good for SEO. I am sure Google does clever translation stuff tho as well.

**[3]** Copy pasting the URL will look funny due to [1] If you look at Arabic wikipedia and try copy paste their url somewhere you will see what I mean.

More information

I know Google does put some weight into what is in the url so for example having page-title.aspx will be better than pagetitle. I would imagine that the same rules apply for having foreign language urls - it will help increase results when people are searching for terms that are included in your arabic word.

Most browsers will deal with it fine I don't think you need to have a special language pack installed. Arabic Wikipedia works fine though the characters get mapped using Internationalized Resource Identifiers.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15539/how-do-special-foreign-language-characters-in-an-url-work-and-are-they-fake

So will look fine in your url bar but will look like this http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A9 when copied.

I always liked how backspace and delete work the other way around with Arabic text.

Comment: I havent' installed any arabic language packs or anything. This is what it looks like. http://imagebin.org/187099

Comment: Does that look right? If so please mark q as resolved = Cheers

Comment: Yes, it looks right...Thanks a lot for your help. I can't find the close option...Where is it?

Comment: You choose my answer as correct and that will put it as 'answered'

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to make the link in number format as the url in arabic doesn't look ok on different search engines ( bing for example )

making the url readable by google not a big ( although it may count to be a good seo practice ) but there is many other good ways to help in that like page title and keywords in page and so on..